# Outlook add-in mailitem.display not working Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, vsto

I'm in the process of converting some outlook VBA macros to an Add-in. I am having difficulty with my macros that create emails based on a template.  I decided to code a simple button to create and display a new email with the subject test.

Everything is working up to displaying the email which doesn't happen.

```
Private Sub ButtonGenEmail_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonGenEmail.Click
    Me.Close()
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    objApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    objMail = objApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
    objMail.Subject = "test"
    objMail.Save()
    objMail.Display(False)
End Sub
```

At one point I added `msgbox "Done"` after `objMail.Display(False)` and the message never appears.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get an error? Can you actually step through your code? Are you sure that code even runs?

Comment: Yes the code works up until objMail.Display(False), objMail.Save() works because I see a new mail in my draft folder.  I've tried objMail.Display(True) and objMail.Display()

Comment: So no error, the sub just quits?

Comment: I don't think it is quiting. If I move the me.close to the end the email gets saved to draft, and the form never closed itself. objMail.Display(False) must be causing Outlook to open the mail in environment space I do not see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should obviously work. I'm not so skilled in Outlook but I guess the problem here is that you run it from a form (*I see the* `Me.Close`) 
Isn't then Outlook blocking to display the mail because the form is still open (I guess modal = `ShowDialog()`)?

I think you will have to either change the form to be not modal (*use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`)* or handle the event after the form is closed, something like

All code below written from top of my mind, so I may miss something

A method **from where you initialize the form**

```
Dim frm as new YourForm()
frm.ShowDialog()

if frm.MyState = TheyClickOnButton Then
  ' Run your mailItem code here
End If
```

in **the form code**

```
Public Enum State
  Unknown = 0
  TheyClickedOnButton
End Enum

Public Property MyState as State

Private Sub ButtonGenEmail_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonGenEmail.Click
    MyState = TheyClickedOnButton
    Me.Close()    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much! I knew it had to been something simple I was missing.  Changing my from.showdialog to form.show did the trick.